# Grails 2.5.6 - using grails.databinding.useSpringBinder

Tags: grails, data-binding

I am upgrading a project from 2.2.4 to 2.5.6.
The binding that worked in 2.2.4 does not work for us in 2.5.6.
So I am trying to get the spring binding working in 2.5.6 to see if that will solve our problem.

I have made 2 changes in the 2.5.6 project to try to get this working

Config.groovy:

```
grails.databinding.useSpringBinder=true
```

BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile 'org.grails:grails-web-databinding-spring:2.5.6'
```

But after doing this the binding is not working for me.
So I have tried with a very simple example, but this also is not working.

```
package simple

@grails.validation.Validateable
class SimpleCommand {

    String name
}
```

package simple

```
class SimpleController {

    def index(SimpleCommand simple) {
        render "Simply " + simple.name
    }
}
```

This works fine when I remove config for using the spring binder, but with it, simple.name is null.

Is there something else I should be doing?

Thanks,

Kenny

Comment: There aren't many good reasons to use the spring binder if you are using Grails 2.5.6.  A better approach would be to figure out why the default binder doesn't work for you.  Can you describe what the default binder isn't doing that you want it to do?

Comment: We have customer facing rest services (POST) that accept the following JSON - { "company.id" : "2", ... } . 2.2.4 binds this to the correct company while 2.5.6 does not. Changing the JSON to { "company" : { "id" : "2" }, ... } works fine in 2.5.6 but we were hoping not to impact the customers.

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828274/grails-2-3-1-command-object-data-binding-at-controller-parameters could be relevant in your scenario

Comment: Thanks for the idea user615274, but had already seen that and tested it, but to no avail.